# Remap keys from a second keyboard in Ubuntu - towards the optimal solution

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to use keys from a second keyboard to create **custom shortcuts** that are useful to me. For example, having to write a lot of math formulas, I'd like to press a key from the second keyboard, let's say the <kbd>a</kbd> key, for writing "\nabla" in a LaTeX editor.

---

At the moment, I'm following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/592829/in-linux-remap-keys-from-second-keyboard-to-unicode-characters-and-shortcuts) answer, that exploits the `actkbd` daemon - [http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/actkbd/](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/%7Ethkala/projects/actkbd/). The answer suggests to use `actkbd` for copying the character(s) I'm interested in to the clipboard, and this solution works nicely. (So far I've just tried with the keyboard of my laptop, since I do not have a second keyboard yet, but I assume I can use `actkbd` only on the second keyboard just by changing the input device in the `actkbd` command, as described in the answer).

Unfortunately, there is one **drawback**: the key that I'm binding is still doing its old job (so after pressing <kbd>a</kbd>, the "a" character will be written in the editor), while I'd like to completely overwrite the action of that key. Therefore, at the moment I could only use those keys that do not affect the writing flow (for example, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, and so on).

Do you have any suggestions on how to adjust this solution in order to "overwrite" the action of those keys?

*OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS*

Comment: If get yourself a keyboard with QMK, the problem just goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would use [kmonad](https://github.com/david-janssen/kmonad) although it is probably overkill. It allows you to redefine every key differently on every connected keyboard. These keys can be traditional keyboard macros, or can act as new modifiers. This allows you to define new "layers" so you can type say Greek or maths. For the specific case of nabla, you can either get the system to type `\` `n` `a` `b` `l` `a` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> depending on your OS to enter the Unicode character directly.

Comment: Thanks @icarus. `kmonad` seems to be such a great solution, it is very structured and in future I could even do more complicated customization, so I'm trying to use it. However, I'm having some difficulties when running it, since some keys are exchanged (for example, `kmonad` types `grv` instead of `\` when I write`\\` in my layer). Do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Only now I noticed the bad formatting of my comment... I meant that when I use 'ḱmonad' it is like the slash is exchanged with some other keys, maybe because I'm using an Italian keyboard layout... however, I will try to deal with that, maybe I'm going to ask directly to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to disable the keys, I followed the instructions on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/8geyru/diy_linux_macro_board/) post on Reddit.

Long story short: the only thing to do is `xinput list` and then `xinput --disable [id]` with the `id` of your second keyboard. The best thing now would be to figure out how to directly paste without copying to the clipboard, but at the moment I will just stick with this good solution.